# WPF and MVVM: bind UserControl to XAML dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

seems like a trivial task: i am building a wpf application, using MVVM pattern. what i want is dynamically change part of a view, using different UserControls, dependent on user input.

let's say, i have got 2 UserControls, one with a button, and another with a label.
in main view i have a container for that. following XAML "works":

```
<GroupBox Header="container" >
    <local:UserControlButton />
</GroupBox>
```

and a UserControl element with buttons pops up. if i change it to another one, it works too.
question is how to feed that groupbox dynamically. if i put something like that in my model view:

```
private UserControl _myControl;
public UserControl MyControl
{
    get
    {
        return _myControl;
    }
    set
    {
        _myControl= value;
        InvokePropertyChanged("MyControl");
    }
}
```

and change my view XAML to something like:

```
<GroupBox Header="container" >
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyControl}" />
</GroupBox>
```

and feed it from command with usercontrol for button or for label: nothing happens, although "MyControl" variable is set and is "invoke property changed"..

Comment: [MVVMLight Using Two Views](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/323187/MVVMLight-Using-Two-Views) have a read through that. It explains the underlying concept. Applying it to your case after that should be simple. btw not sure what you mean by `model view`. Do you mean `ViewModel`? if so you wouldnt have UI elements in a VM in the first place. Read through the linked article and possibly the previous one too to help

Comment: Please see my answer to the [Navigating through multiple child views contained in Main Window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23137371/navigating-through-multiple-child-views-contained-in-main-window/23137536#23137536) question. While it is not exactly the same as your example, you should still be able to fulfil your requirements by following the advice there.

Comment: @Sheridan +1 I was just about to link to that answer of yours...

Comment: Thanks, my friend. I was going to close this question as a duplicate of that one, but you know what these users are like... *it's not EXACTLY the same as my question...*

Comment: @Sheridan is it against MVVM bind a user control in a VM? I was expecting HighCore's "delete code and use MVVM," heh.

Comment: @Netscape, yeah we're not supposed to have any UI related classes in the view model, but then it really depends on how professional your application is. If you have a professional application, then you probably have suites of unit tests and then having UI elements in the view models will cause problems. However, if you're just roughly following the MVVM methodology because it just makes working with WPF easier and it's not a big application, then it doesn't *really* matter. It's kind of like having your data access classes in a separate project... only really required in a pro application.

Comment: you are right, that link you posted answers my question. you can delete these one as duplicate if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously there are many ways to skin this particular cat - but to answer the question of why it doesn't work you need to look into the ItemsSource property of ItemsControl on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The items control is designed to show multiple items, provided through an `IEnumerable` passed to the ItemsSource property.  You are passing a UserControl, so the binding will fail.

For your example, I would change the ItemsControl to a ContentControl and bind the content to your `MyControl` property.  This should then work.

```
<GroupBox Header="container" >
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding MyControl}" />
</GroupBox>
```

However, I would strongly recommend looking into other ways of doing this - having a control in your VM breaks MVVM to my mind.  Depending on what you are doing look at data templates - @Sheridan's link in the comments provides an great description of a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't post this as a comment so adding as answer..

Have a look at this:
[Implementing an own "Factory" for reusing Views in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24271121/implementing-an-own-factory-for-reusing-views-in-wpf/24376379#24376379)

It uses DataTemplates but doesn't require the DataTemplate section for each view. If you potentially have a lot of user controls/views you wish to display or you are reusing through multiple views or you are intending to actually dynamically generate a view (versus just loading an existing user control) then this might suite your needs.